# Firestore Query with search in document and sub-collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an employee document (name, designation, ...) and a sub-collection containing all the shifts (documents of the sub-collection) assigned to this employee.

When assigning a new shift, I want to retrieve only the employees that have a particular designation, meaning they are skilled to perform this shift.

Furthermore, I should search within the sub-collection and fetch only the employees that do not have a document for the same date of the shift to assign.

At the moment I only know how to retrieve the employees that have a particular designation.

What I am not able to implement is the part where I only get the skilled employees that are free on the day of the shift to assign.

```
 @override
  Stream<List<Employee>> availableEmployeesForGivenDesignation(String designation, DateTime statusDate) {
    return _employeeCollection
        .where('designation', isEqualTo: designation)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
         //todo search in the sub-collection
          ...
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore queries only work across a single type of collection. There is no way to search both employees and their shifts in a single query, you will need at least two queries for that.

To allow your use-case with a single query, you'll have to duplicate data. You had two options there:

1. Duplicate the necessary shift data into the employee document, and then query only the employee collection.
2. Duplicate the necessary employee data into their shift documents, and then perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all shifts collections.

Given what you described the second option sounds most promising. It'd look something like this:

```
db.collectionGroup("shifts")
  .where('designation', isEqualTo: designation)
  .where(...your other condition...)
  .snapshots()
  .map((snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.reference.parent().parent().documentID);
  })
```

You'd then use that document ID to look up the employee document.

Comment: So you mean, pass some employee data as fields to the shift document found in a respectable sub-collection. I still do not know how to get only the employees with no shifts for a given date. Remember, I only want to get the selection of available employees.

Comment: You can't search for documents **without** a value. So you might want to consider inserting all shifts and then keep a "is booked" field in there.  The only alternatives I can think of are to: 1) keep a map of available in the employee document (option 1 in my answer), 2) load each employee and query their shifts separately subcollection separately to see if there's any results.

Comment: This is great stuff. Which option would be more cost-efficient, if I would keep within the employee document up to two weeks of availability data (map dates as keys and bool as value)?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question to me. But cost is fairly simple: do a napkin calculation of how many documents are read, how many are written, and how much data is read, and put them into the [pricing calculator](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#blaze-calculator).