# How to make a query that retrieve a collection and a subcollection in firebase with angularfire?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've the following structure in my firebase DB:

```
/profiles/{uid}/displayName
               /email
               /otherAttribues
               /roles/{roleName}/someAttribute
                                /someOtherAttribute
```

So "roles" is a subcollection, mostly because it has to have different writes rights than the rest of the profile.

In my component, I currently retrieve the profiles:

```
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.users$ = this.firestore.collection<User>('profiles').valueChanges();
  }
```

In my html, I'm using this `users$` in a `*ngFor` loop to display the profiles in the grid. I need to add one column that will be shown based on the presence/absence of a role with the ID "admin" or "user". This can be modified from other users, so it has to be an observable.

How can I retrieve the "roles" of my profile(at least the IDs of the documents in the subcollection) and still iterate on them nicely?

This can change, so I need this to be an observable. I cannot find a way to "include" a subcollection in my request.

And based on the roles, I need to have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the following in my user component:

```
this.users$ = this.firestore.collection<User>('profiles').valueChanges({ idField: 'uid' }).pipe(
      switchMap((profiles) => {
        const res = profiles.map(profile => {
          return this.firestore.collection(`profiles/${profile.uid}/roles`).valueChanges({ idField: 'Id' }).pipe(
            map(doc => {
              return doc.map(d => d.Id)
            }),
            tap(roles => {
              //TODO: consolidate the profile with the roles here
              //This will be updated on changes
            }),
            map(roles => Object.assign(profile, { roles }))
          );
        })
        return combineLatest(...res);
      })
    );
```

Note: it warns me about the deprecation of combineLatest, but not sure how to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore reads are shallow, they only read from the collection (group) that you name, so from `user` in your case. There is no way to also read from the subcollection in the same operation.

There are two common options to information about the user's roles:

1. Perform an extra read operation, either for each individual user, or by a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for all `roles` collections in one go.
2. By duplicating the relevant information from `roles` into the parent document in `user`.

Given how simple your query requirement is, I'd likely choose to (also) store the information in the `user` document, either from the client directly, or through a Cloud Function that is triggered whenever the `roles` data is updated.

Comment: 1. How can you do a group query to consolidate each object with the subcollection?
2. I cannot duplicate, they do not have the same write permissions, so it would mean that an user could promotes himself admin for some features

Comment: 2) You could reject changes to that specific field in the security rules. 1) I'm not sure I understand. If you're wondering how to determine what user document a certain role document belong to, that'd be a matter of following the chain of `parent` properties upwards similar to what I show here for Flutter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61713774.

Comment: Hi @Frank, thank you for your answer, but I must admit your answer wasn't really usefull, since it was in a different collection, it was kind of obvious that this was needing an extra needs, I just didn't know how to do this with map/tap/switchmap/combineLatest operators. Kinda new with the RXJS world, I'm much more used to the async/await patterns